# Why R'Moshe Fenstein considers whey as being pareve?

Tags: meat-and-milk, dairy

Why does he considers whey as being pareve whereas it is clearly pareve only mideoraita and not midrabanan (according to Tosfot, the Rosh considers it as being dairy even mideoraita)?

Sources: http://www.dafyomi.co.il/chulin/insites/ch-dt-114.htm
https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/dairy-primer/ (point IV)

Comment: From your article, it seems he was clearly convinced that whey was the Mei Chalav the tamud labels as pareve. Regarding the Rosh, he might have a different interpretation of the difference between nisubei dechalva OR he might hold that the micro-filtration used by modern plants renders it mei chalav even according to the Rosh and would make it muttar even miderabanan

Comment: Thanks! But the Talmud labels Mei Chalav as pareve MIDEORAITA only.

Comment: @far22 It's clear from both sources that R"M held modern whey was mei chalav, so it clearly avoids the Rosh and the S"A on nesuvei chalba being assur either de'oraisa or derabanan. Specifically the Beit Yosef claimed mei chalav was assur miderabanan. Alas I do not have a copy to check his language, but perhaps R'Moshe disagrees with the B"Y regarding this (that the rebanan didn't rule on mei chalav)?

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky thanks! It does not avoid Tosfot saying mei halav is pareve only mideoraita (BY seems to follow Tosfot on this point). Perhaps the answer is that R'Fenstein only follows the Rosh but the Rosh wrote that whey is Nesuvei Chalba! In this case, why does R Fenstein held that modern whey is different from ancient whey (and that it is mei chalav and not nesuvei chalba)? So there is a problem with both Tosfot and the Rosh.

Comment: Both Tosafot and the Rosh are operating on the assumption that whey is nesuvei chalba (tosafos just doesn't distinguish like the Rosh does). R"M seems to understand that the issue is that the whey is still a colloidal suspension of solid particles in a liquid (like milk) and that the solid particles are what makes the whey milchig. That is why whey, which is rov liquid, is considered pareve mideoraita but assur miderabanan. If filtering the whey removes the solid milchig particles, then the remaining liquid would definitely be pareve according to this understanding.

Comment: Thanks! So the main difference between modern whey and ancient whey would be the filtering. So modern whey is, according to R' Fenstein, a step above ancient whey due to the filtering. The problem here is that modern whey would be, for those who consider it as being nesuvei chalba, only Mei Halav (the step after nesuvei chalba). Only for those who consider it as being mei halav, it would then be mei mei halav and therefore completely mutar.

Comment: R"Moshe is giving his halachic understanding. If you're disagreeing with his premise then you can't legitimately ask on his conclusions. At the end of the day, he disagrees with the Rosh and B"Y. My comments provide a possible reasoning (modern filtration) but are offered without access to the relevant texts. It's not a "problem" that there are those who consider whey nesuvei chalba - he didn't, and that's the question you're asking.

Comment: I don't disagree with his premise I just try to understand it. I think you summed up everything in your comment. R'Fenstein disagree with the Rosh and the S'A' on this issue therefore whey is for him mei mei halav and not dairy. Thanks man ;) btw, is that you that downvoted the question?

Comment: nah, that wasn't me.