# Do Jews to have wait for whey after meat

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk, yoreh-deah, leniencies

According to Halacha, if a Jew eats meat, do they have to wait after eating meat to consume whey, or do they merely have to finish eating, wash their mouth, and drink water? Are the rules for whey different when it comes to waiting after meat relative to milk or no?

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%96_%D7%97

Comment: @DoubleAA , what do we call whey nowadays ,the liquid from cheese or after the boil ?

Comment: https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/what-is-the-status-of-lactose-and-whey-are-they-considered-to-be-milchig/

Comment: related (unanswered) Q: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71420/why-rmoshe-fenstein-considers-whey-as-being-pareve

Comment: From Rav Eliyashiv's teshuva in Kovetz Teshuvos 1:73 that eating(drinking) whey after meat is permissible (seemingly ) based off the reading of the Shach. This is in reference to Mei chalav. Will post as answer when have a moment .

Comment: Whey still contains some milk solids making it dairy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @sam R’ Elyashiv says it’s mutar. Although, eating them together is prohibited, he says that is an issue of maaris ayin but it is not counted as Bonafide milk for the waiting periods.

Here is a picture of the Teshuva I found online

[image: r Elyashiv whey]

Edit: this answer is referring to whey permeate, and lactose. Regular whey that has solid pieces in it, would be milichig.

Furthermore, the Chasam Sofer in [YD 73](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14664&st=&pgnum=51&hilite=) says that one who is ill and must drink whey after meat, may do so after waiting one hour.

Comment: Are lactose and whey the same thing?

Comment: The OU seems to equate the two. https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/what-is-the-status-of-lactose-and-whey-are-they-considered-to-be-milchig/

Comment: Why should waiting not apply to dairy derabanan if it does to meat derabanan (chicken)

Comment: This seems to disagree with the other answer about issur hanaah

Comment: @DoubleAA yes it does seem to disagree.

Comment: Lactose and whey are not the same and this teshuva is not about whey

Answer (score 1):

The Star-K has an [article](https://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/706/meat-and-dairy-a-kosher-consumers-handbook/) discussing mixtures of meat and dairy. While the article doesn't discuss your question directly, it says as follows:

> One may not derive benefit from dairy and meat mixtures that were heated together. Therefore, one may not feed his pet food that contains both meat and dairy, because feeding one’s pet is considered “deriving benefit.” Pet food labels should carefully be checked to avoid meat and milk mixtures.<sup>45</sup>

[Note 45](https://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/706/meat-and-dairy-a-kosher-consumers-handbook/#:%7E:text=45.%20For%20example,not%20cooked%20together.) then says as follows:

> ...if the label states **beef or meat AND milk, casein or whey**, one may not feed it to his pet. Although the following may not be consumed by a Jew, one may feed them to his pet: chicken and milk, pork and milk, and horsemeat and milk (even if they were heated), and milk and meat that were not cooked together.

The Star-K here is including whey in the issur of *deriving pleasure from the mixture* basar b'cholov with regard to whey. More explicitly, the Star-K in [this article](https://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/375/feeding-your-pet-barking-up-the-right-tree/#fB:%7E:text=One%20should%20be%20aware%20that%20casein%20and%20whey15%20are%20considered%20milk%2C%20and%20animal%20fat%20is%20considered%20meat.), quoting Badei Hashulchan 87:75, refers to whey as dairy:

> One should be aware that casein and whey are considered milk, and animal fat is considered meat.

With comparisons to milk, and no reference to any [heter to the contrary](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/141001/17821), we can therefore conclude that - according to the Star-K - whey constitutes a milk product such that one must *x* hours after eating meat prior to consuming whey.

Comment: While not a bad inference, a more direct proof would be preferable